# Get all Projects names in your SonarQube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

There used to be "api/resources/" api to realize this.
But unfortunately its not in my v6.4.

I tried "/api/qualitygates/search?gateId=1" after confirming that the Default Qualitygate is "SonarQube way" using this api to confirm it "api/qualitygates/list"
but I get.

```
{"more":false,"results":[]}
```

Is there any easy way to get all the projects in my SonarQube server by the API?

Comment: i am not sure, but maybe this link will help: https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/resources

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
http://my-domain/api/components/search?qualifiers=TRK
```

This gave me the list of projects in sonar

In the link below click on the parameters section to see for other possible values
https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/components

Answer (score 6):

This will also give list of projects

`http://sonar-domain/api/projects/search?qualifiers=TRK&ps=500`

Response:

```
{
  "paging": {
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 500,
    "total": 2
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "organization": "my-org-1",
      "id": "project-uuid-1",
      "key": "project-key-1",
      "name": "Project Name 1",
      "qualifier": "TRK",
      "visibility": "public",
      "lastAnalysisDate": "2017-03-01T11:39:03+0300"
    },
    {
      "organization": "my-org-1",
      "id": "project-uuid-2",
      "key": "project-key-2",
      "name": "Project Name 1",
      "qualifier": "TRK",
      "visibility": "private",
      "lastAnalysisDate": "2017-03-02T15:21:47+0300"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the `ps=500` parameter, very useful.

Comment: it is working with username/password, but if i pass access token am getting response in html fortmat. and i have created that access token under admin profile only.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it's deprecated.

> Removed since 6.3, please use api/components and api/measures instead

[image: Screenshot from my local copy of SonarQube 6.4.]

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you give a sample to execute "api/components" and "api/measures" without prior knowing the key or componentId of projects on the SonarQube server.
I have seen below formats and not suitable for getting all the projects on the server.
https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/components/show?key=postgresql
Get the desired metrics:
https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/measures/component?componentId=6d75286c-42bb-4377-a0a1-bfe88169cffb&metricKeys=sqale_debt_ratio&additionalFields=metrics,periods

Comment: @electricalbah So If i understand correctly, you require a list of all the available projects.

This can be done by passing the GET parameter `qualifiers` and using the value `TRK` for it

Docs - https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/components/search

example - 

http://sonar.server.com/api/components/search?qualifiers=TRK